# How to Combine "Year", "Day of the Year", and "Hour" columns to DateTime in R?

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr, lubridate

I have long dataframe as below (Note: DoY: Day of the Year, Hour: Hour of the Day (e.g., Hour =0.5 means 12:30 AM):

```
Year   DoY   Hour
2016   126   0.5
2016   126   1
2016   126   1.5
 -      -     -
2016   127   0
2016   127   0.5
 -      -     -
2018   300   23.5
 -      -     -
```

I am trying to combine these columns to single DateTime column (e.g. 2016-05-05 12:30 AM, 2016-05-05 1:00 AM, etc.). I tried following code:

```
x <- as.numeric(df$Hour)
x.m <- paste(floor(x), round((x-floor(x))*60), sep=":")
df$HourMinute <- x.m 
df$DateTime <- strptime(paste0(df$Year, df$DoY, df$HourMinute), format = "%Y%j%H:%M")
```

Above code results into some strange output. After a Year end, It outputs NA values. How to create the desired output column?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "after a year end"?

Comment: What I mean by "after a year end" is that the code I wrote above works fine for a year (e.g., 2016) but It creates NA value in the beginning of next year (i.e., 2017 and 2018).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `lubridate`:

```r
library(lubridate)

df$date <- make_datetime(year = df$Year, min = round(df$Hour*60)) + days(df$DoY-1)

df

#>   Year DoY Hour                date
#> 1 2016 126  0.5 2016-05-05 00:30:00
#> 2 2016 126  1.0 2016-05-05 01:00:00
#> 3 2016 126  1.5 2016-05-05 01:30:00
```

Data :

```
df <- structure(list(Year = c(2016L, 2016L, 2016L), DoY = c(126L, 126L, 126L), 
                     Hour = c(0.5, 1, 1.5)),
                     class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-3L))
```

Comment: Glad it helped! Note my small edit : I removed 1 day from `days(df$DoY-1)`

Comment: Why did you remove 1 day? My DateTime output is correct when I use following formula df$date <- make_datetime(year = df$Year, min = round(df$Hour*60)) + days(df$DoY). I think we don't need to remove 1 day.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback : I think this depends on how DoY is defined. `make_datetime(year)` starts with the first day of the year and we add `DoY` to it. If `DoY` is 1, it will result in 1+1 = 2nd day. What is the definition of `DoY`on your side?

Comment: My mistake! Actually, I ignored leap year day in my calculation which lead to an incorrect calculation. Your formula is correct. We should remove 1 day which will work OK in all cases. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a base R way.

```
fun <- function(DF){
  d <- with(DF, paste(Year, DoY))
  d <- as.Date(d, "%Y %j")
  hm <- DF[["Hour"]]*60
  d <- paste(d, paste(hm %/% 60, hm %% 60, 0, sep = ":"))
  d <- as.POSIXct(d, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
  d
}

fun(df)
#[1] "2016-05-05 00:30:00" "2016-05-05 01:00:00"
#[3] "2016-05-05 01:30:00"
```

This result can be assigned to a new column in the usual way.

```
df$DateTime <- fun(df)
```

---

**Data**

```
df <- read.table(text = "
Year   DoY   Hour
2016   126   0.5
2016   126   1
2016   126   1.5
", header = TRUE)
```